# Ruby on Rails Nested resources undefined method path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've defined nested resources in the /config/routes.rb

```
  resources :goals do
    resources :goal_entries
  end
```

Models for Goal:

```
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :code, :description, :from_date, :to_date
  validates_uniqueness_of :code
  validates_presence_of :code
  has_many :goal_entries, :primary_key => "code", :foreign_key => "goal_code"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :goal_entries
end
```

and for GoalEntry :

```
class GoalEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :code, :goal_code,
  :general_increase_percentage, :general_net_sales,
  belongs_to :goal, :primary_key => "code", :foreign_key => "goal_code"
  validates_presence_of :code
  validates_presence_of :goal_code
  validates_uniqueness_of :code , :scope => :goal_code
  #validates_numericality_of :general_net_sales
```

The view to create/edit a GoalEntry for the Goal parent starts like this:

```
<%= form_for([@goal, @goal_entry]) do |f| %>
<% if @goal_entry.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@goal_entry.errors.count, "error") %>
        prohibited this goal_entry from being saved:
    </h2>
    <ul>
        <% @goal_entry.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :goal_code, :required => true%>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :code %>
    <%= f.number_field :code, :required => true %>
</div>
...
```

The update method in the goal entries controller:

```
  def update
    @goal_entry = GoalEntry.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @goal_entry.update_attributes(params[:goal_entry])
        format.html { redirect_to edit_goal_path(@goal_entry.goal), notice: 'Goal entry was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @goal_entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Entering valid Goal entries works fine. But if there's a validation error message I get the following Message:

```
    **NoMethodError in Goal_entries#update**
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `goal_entry_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fce30a0c160>:0x00000004199570>):
    1: <%= form_for([@goal, @goal_entry]) do |f| %>
    2: <% if @goal_entry.errors.any? %>
    3: <div id="error_explanation">
    4:  <h2><%= pluralize(@goal_entry.errors.count, "error") %>
  app/views/goal_entries/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_goal_entries__form_html_erb__827873423371803667_70261777948540'
  app/views/goal_entries/edit.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_goal_entries_edit_html_erb__779650500016633360_70261777920720'
  app/controllers/goal_entries_controller.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in update'
  app/controllers/goal_entries_controller.rb:72:in `update'
    etc...
```

Is there something wrong with `<% if @goal_entry.errors.any? %>`
I'll appreciate if somebody has a solution for this. Thanks

Comment: `undefined method 'goal_entry_path'` are you sure there's a goal_entry_path in your routes? If there is, can you post your edit method?

Comment: Does your `edit` action has the following `@goal_entry = GoalEntry.find(params[:id])` ?

Comment: Can you post what `rake routes` prints out?

Comment: Delameko solved this problem: adding '@goal = Goal.find(params[:goal_id])' to the update method solved it. The edit method had it and I assume that's why it worked when there were no validation messages to be reported.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your form_for is generating its route from `[@goal, @goal_entry]` but you haven't defined @goal in your update action.

Try adding `@goal = Goal.find(params[:goal_id])` to your update method.

Comment: I still don't understand, why everything works fine, when there are no validation messages ! And the message I got is a little bit confusing: it says undefined 'goal_entry_path' and not 'goal_path' ? I'm surely missing something.

Comment: To answer your second part first, the `[@goal, @goal_entry]` is generating the route `goal_goal_entry_path(@goal)` (you can check `rake routes` on the command line to see a list of all your routes and how they're generated).  When @goal isn't defined its using just @goal_entry and trying to generate a goal_entry_path (which you'll see on `rake routes` doesn't exist because goal_entry is nested under goal).

Comment: If you look in your update action you'll see the line `if @goal_entry.update_attributes(params[:goal_entry])`.  When it successfully updates it redirects to the edit_goal page.  However, if your validation fails then update_attributes fails and it'll run `render action: "edit"` line.  Basically, this line is rendering the edit view within the update action (if that makes sense), so it needs access to the same variables that the edit action uses.

Comment: Understood. Thanks again @Delameko, for your clear explanation!